# Bash Read Escaped Characters and Normal Characters

Tags: bash, shell, input, io

I want to read in bash when *any key is pressed*, be it arrow key, number, letter, or punctuation, without pressing enter.

This is the closest that I have come up with, besides that when an escaped key is pressed, it spills over into the next input. Also, escaped keys will read but not echo.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -n 1 -d $'\n' -p 'input> ' line
echo -en "\n"
echo "$line"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hacky/dirty way, but should work for user interactive shells...

```
read -n1 -s -p 'input> ' line; read -t 0.1 -n2 -s line2
line="$line$line2"
```

Now, it's up to you to convert `<ESC>[A` to string `<UP>` or not.

NOTE: It would most likely fail, if the stdin is redirected (say, from pipe/file...)

Comment: "hacky/dirty"... Almost perfect.

Comment: Just realized that similar approach is already given at TLDP : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html#BASHEK

Comment: Yes. This example will not work on OS X, however, because the read times on a Mac need to be positive integers. The only way the TLDP program works is if there can be very short read times following the first read time.

Comment: ^^ Correct. as I said, it would only work for interactive shells, when the user is going to press a key, manually. & as you found out, it would not work for OSX. But on OSX, you can still compile a custom binary `myread` & use it as `line=\`myread\``...

Comment: What about long escape sequences? (For instance, my Ctrl-F2 key generates "\e[O1;5Q".  And what about really really fast typers?  I am pretty sure that sometimes more than one key gets pressed within 0.1 seconds.

Comment: @alfe: For first question, you can extend the above logic, `$line1` for simple character, `$line1$line2` for arrow keys, `$line1$line2$line3` for ctrl+F2 like combination.

Comment: For 2nd question, you can alter the delay. But, for 5-95 %le people, _hopefully_ this will work.

Comment: Consider pasted long text.  Consider strange terminals which create escape sequences of various lengths.  What we really need is a function which states of a received escape sequence whether it is complete or unfinished.  Then we can continue reading as long as it is unfinished.  I'm still searching for such a thing.  `terminfo` and `tput` are starting points, but I'm not successful yet.