# bash scripting - read single keystroke including special keys enter and space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, special-characters, keystroke

Not sure if I should put this on stackoverflow or unix.stackexchange but I found some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612274/bash-shell-scripting-return-key-enter-key) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712430/bash-read-escaped-characters-and-normal-characters) here, so here it goes.

I'm trying to create a script to be called by .bashrc that allows me to select one of two options based on a single keystroke. That wouldn't be hard normally but I want the two keys corresponding to the two options to be space and enter.

Here's what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

SELECT=""
while [[ "$SELECT" != $'\x0a' && "$SELECT" != $'\x20' ]]; do
    echo "Select session type:"
    echo "Press <Enter> to do foo"
    echo "Press <Space> to do bar"
    read -s -N 1 SELECT
    echo "Debug/$SELECT/${#SELECT}"
    [[ "$SELECT" == $'\x0a' ]] && echo "enter" # do foo
    [[ "$SELECT" == $'\x20' ]] && echo "space" # do bar
done
```

The following output is what I get if I press enter, space, backspace and x:

```
:~$ bin/sessionSelect.sh
Select session type:
Press <Enter> to start/resume a screen session
Press <Space> for a regular ssh session
Debug//0
Select session type:
Press <Enter> to start/resume a screen session
Press <Space> for a regular ssh session
Debug//0
Select session type:
Press <Enter> to start/resume a screen session
Press <Space> for a regular ssh session
Debug//1
Select session type:
Press <Enter> to start/resume a screen session
Press <Space> for a regular ssh session
Debug/x/1
```

So both enter and space result in an empty SELECT. No way to distinguish the two. I tried to add -d 'D' to the read options, but that didn't help. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

The bash version would be 4.2 btw.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179191/bashscript-to-detect-right-arrow-key-being-pressed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the read delimiter to an empty string then check the builtin $REPLY variable:

```
read -d'' -s -n1
```

For some reason I couldn't get it to work specifying a variable.

Comment: This works nicely, even without changing the delimiter with -d. Both enter and space are correctly detected.

Comment: We've probably got different flavors of `read`. If I leave out -d'', I don't get the enter key.

Comment: I only just noticed that we use -n and -N respectively. That must be the reason for that, when specifying the length with -N newlines aren't treated specially.

Comment: I was going to test with the -N option, but my read doesn't have it.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
SELECT=""
# prevent parsing of the input line
IFS=''
while [[ "$SELECT" != $'\x0a' && "$SELECT" != $'\x20' ]]; do
  echo "Select session type:"
  echo "Press <Enter> to do foo"
  echo "Press <Space> to do bar"
  read -s -N 1 SELECT
  echo "Debug/$SELECT/${#SELECT}"
  [[ "$SELECT" == $'\x0a' ]] && echo "enter" # do foo
  [[ "$SELECT" == $'\x20' ]] && echo "space" # do bar
done
```

Comment: `IFS=''` is not required. `read -N` will return input as-is, ignoring IFS (see man page). Tested this without `IFS=''`, works fine. Great answer! Used this to implement my own version of '--More--'.

Comment: @Maxxim It might be in a newer Bash version. At least for Centos 7.6 with bash-4.2.46(2) the `IFS=''` is required.

Comment: You are correct. The change was introduced in **Bash 4.4**. In the `man` page on `read -N nchars`, the following was added: _[...] The result is not split on the characters in IFS; the intent is that the variable is assigned exactly the characters read (with the exception of backslash; see the -r option below)._ Care to edit your answer and point that out, would help others?

Comment: @Maxxim based on this (unofficial) [list of changes](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES), it's hard to say how exactly the given bash instance behaves (there were many bugs with the IFS treatment). Also do not forget about [backporting](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things about `read` that are relevant here:

- It reads a single line
- The line is split into fields as with word splitting

Since you're reading one character, it implies that entering <kbd>Enter</kbd> would result into an empty variable.

Moreover, by default rules for word splitting, entering <kbd>Space</kbd> would also result into an empty variable.  The good news is that you could handle this part by setting `IFS`.

Change your `read` statement to:

```
IFS= read -s -n 1 SELECT
```

and expect a null string instead of `$'\x0a'` when entering <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This works as well and with setting IFS only for the read command is basically as clean a solution. I still marked putnamhill's as the correct one because it can't produce accidental side effects through a changed IFS. Upvoted though!

Btw, with -N instead of -n SELECT is not empty when sending enter but actually contains the expected value.