# Bash: how to stop a loop when a specific key is pressed, such as Q?

Tags: bash

I need to create a while loop that continuously loops until a key press is registered, specifically the 'q' key for quit.

Here's my (failed) attempt:

```
while [ -z "$QUIT" ]
do
    <Script stuff>
done &
read -sn 1 QUIT
export QUIT
```

However the while loop doesn't exit / end if I press any key. This is because $QUIT seems to only be accessible 'forwards' from where it is set, not backwards to the parent while loop section. Is there a way around this, or an alternative method for allowing my while loop to exit when a key (q if possible) is pressed?

Cheers.

Comment: Read never is reaching. If you want to do that create a file with the pid to stop the process.

Comment: If you launch the script with & and export QUIT=1 . It works.

Comment: Thanks. Is there not a possible way to do it just in 1 file though, for simplicity's sake?

Comment: You could do something similar https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235626/how-to-bind-commands-like-ctrlc-to-one-key-for-example-f5

Comment: Your idea was that https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016046/9799449

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
while true
do
    # Suck in characters until we timeout, collecting sequence
    seq=
    while IFS= read -s -n1 -t 0.01 key; do
        [ "$key" = "" ] && key=" "
        seq="${seq}${key}"
    done

    # Do whatever processing for seq

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing how to kill a background job

```
while true
do
    echo "hello"
    sleep 1
done &

while read -sn 1 QUIT && [[ $QUIT != 'q' ]];
do
    echo "QUIT $QUIT"
done

# This kills the background job
kill %1
```