# How to create a shell script that asks for user input using the space bar?

Tags: shell, installation, radio-button

I would like to create a shell script that asks the user to select radio buttons using the space bar. I have searched a lot but wasn't able to find anything.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this thread for how to record the  key stroke: [bash scripting - read single keystroke including special keys enter and space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842896/bash-scripting-read-single-keystroke-including-special-keys-enter-and-space)

However, you will need to also use need to echo the options provided to the same lines, instead of writing new lines:  [How to show and update echo on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628327/how-to-show-and-update-echo-on-same-line)

So in this case, your script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

SELECT=""
while [[ "$SELECT" != $'\x0a' && "$SELECT" != $'\x20' ]]; do
    echo "Press <Space> to move selection"
    echo "Press <Enter> to confirm selection"
    read -d'' -s -n1
    echo "Debug/$SELECT/${#SELECT}"
    [[ "$SELECT" == $'\x0a' ]] && echo "enter" # do your install stuff
    [[ "$SELECT" == $'\x20' ]] && echo "space" && echo -ne "$options" # reprint options  
done
```

Edit: Actually `printf` probably would be better in this case.

Comment: It does not work very well with me, I can't see the "enter" when I press enter and I can't see the "space" when I press space, all I can see is Debug//0